# Как инициализировать в пустом проекте pytorch скачанную с GitHub нейронную сеть?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, загрузка, pytorch

Скачал данный проект https://github.com/Uehwan/rmd. Он предназначается для pytorch, насколько я понял(но проверяли они на ubuntu, я хочу запустить на win10). Лежит всё в одной папке на диске.

Как мне добавить этот проект в свой пустой проект pytorch? Как начать работать с этим?

Comment: Удалось получить матрицы и веса нейронной сети с помощью данного кода. `device=torch.device('cuda:0')  Net=torch.load('baseline_densenet_nyuv2.pth',map_location=device)                       print(Net)`  Но как теперь мне узнать какие операции я могу с ней выполнять? Эта сеть должна принимать на вход картинку 640х480. А в ответ выдавать картину глубины исходного изображения.

Comment: чтобы "узнать какие операции я могу с ней выполнять" у вас есть два пути -  либо разбираться в коде скаченного скрипта, либо написать его автору, что-бы он вам все подробно разжевал. Что из этого вы хотите, что-бы за вас сделали на этом форуме?

Comment: @passant, я предполагал, что если работа выкладывается в общий доступ, то где то должно быть подробное описание инструментария. Дело в том что даже вопросов подобных нет, хотя тема должна быть популярная! По этому решил что я чего то не знаю об этом. Как Вы думаете, можно ли определить размерность первого тензора? Или функционал pytorch и python не позволяет этого?

Comment: Во-первых, никто никому ничего не должен. Во-вторых, вот подробное описание  проекта https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.12496.pdf но описания "как добавить этот проект в свой пустой проект" там точно не будет. В третьих, и pytorch и python позволяют определить размерность любого объекта.

Comment: @passant, ответ не оправданно агрессивный :) Я не имел в виду что это чья то обязанность, а имел в виду что нет смысла в публикации без объяснения :) Такое ощущение что я должен был это всё знать и задавая вопрос тут же на него ответить)) Я действительно хочу разобраться, но не знаю как подступиться. На странице проекта к примеру есть код jupiter notebook. Но запустить без ошибок код из за ошибок с import`ами я не смог.